# Running Hausdorff distance and colorize by vertex quality doesnt export the color and quality

Tags: meshlab

I am running Hausdorff Distance  filter from meshlabserver and I want to save the Sampled Mesh with the coloring of the vertices.
The distance is computed and I get it in the shell output and the log file.
When exporting the output to *.ply I don't get the vertices quality and colors.

I'm running the following command: 
`meshlabserver -i first.stl -i second.stl -o out.ply -m vc vq -s script.mlx`

Where script.mlx contains the following:

```
<FilterScript>
 <filter name="Remove Duplicate Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Hausdorff Distance">
  <Param value="1" tooltip="The mesh whose surface is sampled. For each sample we search the closest point on the Target Mesh." name="SampledMesh" type="RichMesh" description="Sampled Mesh"/>
  <Param value="0" tooltip="The mesh that is sampled for the comparison." name="TargetMesh" type="RichMesh" description="Target Mesh"/>
  <Param value="false" tooltip="Save the position and distance of all the used samples on both the two surfaces, creating two new layers with two point clouds representing the used samples." name="SaveSample" type="RichBool" description="Save Samples"/>
  <Param value="true" tooltip="For the search of maxima it is useful to sample vertices and edges of the mesh with a greater care. It is quite probably the the farthest points falls along edges or on mesh vertexes, and with uniform montecarlo sampling approachesthe probability of taking a sample over a vertex or an edge is theoretically null.&lt;br>On the other hand this kind of sampling could make the overall sampling distribution slightly biased and slightly affects the cumulative results." name="SampleVert" type="RichBool" description="Sample Vertexes"/>
  <Param value="true" tooltip="See the above comment." name="SampleEdge" type="RichBool" description="Sample Edges"/>
  <Param value="false" tooltip="See the above comment." name="SampleFauxEdge" type="RichBool" description="Sample FauxEdge"/>
  <Param value="true" tooltip="See the above comment." name="SampleFace" type="RichBool" description="Sample Faces"/>
  <Param value="30514" tooltip="The desired number of samples. It can be smaller or larger than the mesh size, and according to the choosed sampling strategy it will try to adapt." name="SampleNum" type="RichInt" description="Number of samples"/>
  <Param min="0" value="233.888" tooltip="Sample points for which we do not find anything whithin this distance are rejected and not considered neither for averaging nor for max." name="MaxDist" type="RichAbsPerc" description="Max Distance" max="468.287"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Colorize by vertex Quality">
  <Param value="0" tooltip="The value that will be mapped with the lower end of the scale (blue)" name="minVal" type="RichFloat" description="Min"/>
  <Param value="0.8" tooltip="The value that will be mapped with the upper end of the scale (red)" name="maxVal" type="RichFloat" description="Max"/>
  <Param min="0" value="0" tooltip="If not zero this value will be used for a percentile cropping of the quality values.&lt;br> If this parameter is set a value P to &lt;i>P&lt;/i> then the two values &lt;i>V_min,V_max&lt;/i> for which &lt;i>P&lt;/i>% of the vertices have a quality &lt;b>lower or greater than &lt;i>V_min,V_max&lt;/i> are used as min/max values for clamping.&lt;br>&lt;br> The automated percentile cropping is very useful for automatically discarding outliers." name="perc" type="RichDynamicFloat" description="Percentile Crop [0..100]" max="100"/>
  <Param value="false" tooltip="If true the min max range will be enlarged to be symmertic (so that green is always Zero)" name="zeroSym" type="RichBool" description="Zero Simmetric"/>
 </filter>
</FilterScript>
```

When Running Hausdorff Distance and Colorize by vertex quality from the GUI MeshLab and export to ply I get the mesh with the quality and colors.

It is possible to get the same behavior from meshlabserver? (even getting only the vertices qualities will be good) 
Am I missing anything?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done same steps than you using my own two meshes. Second mesh is generated by a `Quadric Decimation` Filter and several `Taubin Smooth` Filters applied to the area in the wings.

[image: My two input meshes]

When I ran your script.mlx in meshlabserver (pre-release version) using the same command, and I had this log:

```
Opening a file with extention ply
Mesh gargoyle.50k.ply loaded has 24511 vn 48939 fn
Opening a file with extention ply
Mesh gargoyle.2k.ply loaded has 1264 vn 2500 fn
output mesh  ./out.ply
vertex color, vertex quality, Apply FilterScript: './script.mlx'
FilterScript
Reading filter with name Remove Duplicate Vertices
Reading filter with name Hausdorff Distance
    Reading Param with name SampledMesh : RichMesh
    Reading Param with name TargetMesh : RichMesh
    Reading Param with name SaveSample : RichBool
    Reading Param with name SampleVert : RichBool
    Reading Param with name SampleEdge : RichBool
    Reading Param with name SampleFauxEdge : RichBool
    Reading Param with name SampleFace : RichBool
    Reading Param with name SampleNum : RichInt
    Reading Param with name MaxDist : RichAbsPerc
Reading filter with name Colorize by vertex Quality
    Reading Param with name minVal : RichFloat
    Reading Param with name maxVal : RichFloat
    Reading Param with name perc : RichDynamicFloat
    Reading Param with name zeroSym : RichBool
Starting Script of 3 actionsfilter: Remove Duplicate Vertices
LOG: 2 Removed 0 duplicated vertices
Removed 0 duplicated vertices
filter: Hausdorff Distance
Sampled  mesh has    1264 vert    2500 face
Searched mesh has   24511 vert   48939 face
Max sampling distance 233.888000 on a bbox diag of 198.622528
LOG: 2 Hausdorff Distance computed
LOG: 2      Sampled 62292 pts (rng: 0) on gargoyle.2k.ply searched closest on gargoyle.50k.ply
LOG: 2      min : 0.000016   max 7.446799   mean : 0.756087   RMS : 1.266457
LOG: 2 Values w.r.t. BBox Diag (201.385788)
LOG: 2      min : 0.000000   max 0.036978   mean : 0.003754   RMS : 0.006289

Removed 0 duplicated vertices
Hausdorff Distance computed
     Sampled 62292 pts (rng: 0) on gargoyle.2k.ply searched closest on gargoyle.50k.ply
     min : 0.000016   max 7.446799   mean : 0.756087   RMS : 1.266457
Values w.r.t. BBox Diag (201.385788)
     min : 0.000000   max 0.036978   mean : 0.003754   RMS : 0.006289

filter: Colorize by vertex Quality
LOG: 2 Quality Range: 0.000250 7.398357; Used (0.000000 0.800000)
Removed 0 duplicated vertices
Hausdorff Distance computed
     Sampled 62292 pts (rng: 0) on gargoyle.2k.ply searched closest on gargoyle.50k.ply
     min : 0.000016   max 7.446799   mean : 0.756087   RMS : 1.266457
Values w.r.t. BBox Diag (201.385788)
     min : 0.000000   max 0.036978   mean : 0.003754   RMS : 0.006289

Quality Range: 0.000250 7.398357; Used (0.000000 0.800000)
Mesh ./gargoyle.2k.ply saved as ./out.ply (1264 vn 2500 fn)
```

My output file has color and quality as expected. The distances in the wings are greater than in the body due to my extra smooths (blue means bigger distances, as seen in the quality histogram).

[image: my output file]

Everything is right in my computer, what can be failing on yours?... I downloaded the official 2016-12 version of meshlab and ran same script using the 2016's meshlabserver. This was the result:

[image]

As your output: No color, every quality value set to zero. But, wait... **That looks like the original 50k model**, not the expected decimated one. Meshlabserver-2016 is saving the first mesh, not the second mesh.

So I rearranged your script.mlx file to sample over mesh 0 instead of mesh 1

```
...
 <filter name="Hausdorff Distance">
  <Param value="0" tooltip="The mesh whose surface is sampled. For each sample we search the closest point on the Target Mesh." name="SampledMesh" type="RichMesh" description="Sampled Mesh"/>
  <Param value="1" tooltip="The mesh that is sampled for the comparison." name="TargetMesh" type="RichMesh" description="Target Mesh"/>
...
```

And ran the new script swapping the order of the input meshes:

```
meshlab-2016.12/src/distrib/meshlabserver -i gargoyle.2k.ply -i gargoyle.50k.ply -o out2.ply  -m vq vc -s script2.mlx
```

The output file out2.ply **has no color, but has correct distances quality values**, so I can load it in meshlab and apply the `Colorize by vertex Quality` there. Hail the almighty Hausdorff Gargoyle!

[image]

Conclusion: You have to choose between updating meshlab to the current pre-release or stay with meshlab-2016 and change the order of your input meshes.